# What is the difference between koi, ai, and renai? 恋、愛、恋愛

Tags: word-choice, words, wago-and-kango

I've been listening to a lot of music, and I've always seen Ai 愛 Koi 恋 and ren'ai 恋愛 used the same. Any help? Thanks! :)

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/love-in-the-air-%E6%84%9B%EF%BD%98%E6%81%8B-%E3%81%82%E3%81%84-vs-%E3%81%93%E3%81%84/2247#2247

Though the linked question doesn't explicitly address 恋愛

Answer (score 8):

恋【こい】 and 恋愛【れんあい】 are basically the same. They both mean romantic love or romance, that feeling based on sexual attraction. 恋 is a [native-Japanese word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato_kotoba) (*wago* or *yamato-kotoba*) whereas 恋愛 is a [Sino-Japanese word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Japanese_vocabulary) (*kango*). Generally speaking, Sino-Japanese words tend to sound more technical or formal, as discussed in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33685/5010), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36422/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17935/5010). 恋愛 is the preferred word in news articles, verdicts and such. Well, in this specific case, 恋愛 is commonly used in casual situations, too. Still, 恋愛 tends to sound somewhat objective, whereas 恋 sounds more...romantic.

愛 is more generic familial love, human love, God's love, etc. The difference from 恋 is already covered in existing questions. See: [Love in the air: 愛ｘ恋 {あい vs こい}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2246/5010) and [Translating a sentence with 恋 and 愛](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56984/5010)